# need to have image dragging option to position images in Gallery

Tags: media

I have created a image content type and upload few images. And then I created another content type for Gallery and using node reference field, I added several images under a  gallery. I followed the tutorial in youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUSpTSTVL0Q

Now I wish I could have dragable like feature, so that I can adjust the serial order of each image in a gallery. Image in 1st order should be cover of the gallery. Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: Did you tried [Draggable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews)?

Comment: thanks, I'nt use it but I'll give a try. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by module called "Draggable Views"